# How to implement common search in mongo id when using dynamic attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection called Example, all the fields of a collection are dynamic. I want to perform a common search. I have no idea how I can do. For example, if I search for "hello" it should return all the objects of a collection which contains name irrespective of the fields the value contained.

Example:

```
{ id: 111234, desc: 'hello world' },     
{ id: 545ttt, title: 'hello title' }, 
{ id: sfsd3, data: 'hello' }
```

My query should return all the above records if I search for hello.
I found a mongoid_search gem but I did not find anything related to dynamic fields search.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1.** Create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) on all fields.

```
db.collection.createIndex({ "$**": "text" },{ name: "TextIndex" })
```

**Step 2.** You can do a simple text search with [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) as following query object:

```
{ $text : { $search: <your string> } }
```

Comment: Thanks Jitendra for your quick reply but as I mention I don't know the fields names to implement indexing. My collection contains dynamic fields.

Comment: When creating a text index on multiple fields, you can use the wildcard specifier ($**). With a wildcard text index, MongoDB indexes every field that contains string data for each document in the collection. So you do not need to specify the field in your query.

Comment: To know more you can read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a "virtual field" that contains concatenated content of all string fields. Then use this with the mongoid_search:

```rb
search_in :search_data

def search_data
  self.attributes.select{|k,v| v.is_a?(String) }.values.join(' ')
end
```

How this works: The `mongoid_search` gem runs the `search_data` method before each save and uses it's output to fill the (hidden) `_keywords` field. This field is then used for the actual search when you're doing something like `YourModel.full_text_search('hello')`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's not true. The code I provided works, because `mongoid_search` gem runs the method when you save the model and uses the method's output to udpate the `_keywords` field in the collection. It then uses the `_keywords` field to perform the actual search. Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: That's interesting. One would think that such an important feature would be documented or at least mentioned in the readme. Not in the specs too. But you appear to be right. My apologies.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No problem, it surprised me as well :) I've added the explanation directly to the answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this example with explanation is now directly in the gem's README: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid_search. Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: Yay, open-source! :)